# Strange issue with ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, node.js, rest

I have created sample Flash-AIR FB application with Node.js REST API. I simply call these REST api's through action script. Since I updated application on FB I am getting following strange behavior.

AS3 function: here are the 2 lines which should make post request to my URL

```
 request.url = "http://sample.com:3137/getData";
 request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
```

===================================================================
Node.js function: here are the lines of code in node.js

```
app.post('/getData', function(req, res){
    //res.send(req.params.paramTest);
    res.send("sending data");

});

app.get('/:methodName', function(req, res){
    //res.sendfile('index.html');
    res.send("In get "+req.params.methodName);
});
```

============================================================================

Here the problem is whenever I call "/getData" with POST request in AS3 it always goes into " app.get('/:methodName' " instead of " app.post('/getData', "

If anyone have any clue please help me.

Thanks,
Swati.

Comment: Issue is resolved.

there was problem in called method name which starts with "get", I simply changes method name to "/userdata" and everything working fine.

Comment: You're able to answer your own question and accept it - this will assist people down the track with similar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved. there was problem in called method name which starts with "get", I simply changes method name to "/userdata" and everything working fine.